# How to continue iteration over a codition even after it has been met once or even multiple times in ruby

Tags: arrays, json, ruby, conditional-statements, conditional-operator

I am writing a small package manager in ruby, and while working on its' package searching functionality, I want to continue iterating over a list of matches, even if it has found a package or sting identical to the inputted string.

```
def makelist(jsn, searchterm)
    len = jsn.length
    n = 0
    while n < len do
      pkname = jsn[n]["Name"]
      pkdesc = jsn[n]["Description"]
      pkver  = jsn[n]["Version"]

      unless pkname != nil || pkdesc != nil
        # skip
      else
        puts "#{fmt(fmt("aur/", 6),0)}#{fmt(pkname,0)} [#{fmt(pkver,8)}]\n    #{pkdesc}"
        n += 1
      end
    end

  end
```

I have tried using an if statement, unless statement and a case statement in which I gave conditions for what it should do if it specifically finds a packages that matches *searchterm* but when I use this condition, it always skips all other conditions and ends the loop, printing only that result. This block of code works, but I want to use my *fmt* function to format the text of matches differently in the list. Anyone have any ideas of how I could accomplish this?

Comment: I don't see how you're doing any matching to the search term in the snipped provided. Can you include the code that doesn't work?

Comment: Also - can you clarify what the makelist function should do?

Comment: @melcher the makelist function reads a parsed json hash that I pull from an RPC and then skips any that contain a nil name or description field, and prints out all the other ones. the parameter *jsn* is the hash, and *searchterm* is a string formatted argument passed to the script in command line. The code that wouldn't work would be using an IF to check that there are no null names/descs then running an else if the *searchterm* is an exact match or contained within the name of one of the hash elements, and then a final else running on the rest of the elements in the hash that dont match exact

Comment: Do you mean - if given a search term, then the results should be limited by it, but if not given a search term, then all results should be returned?

Comment: @melcher I want to be able to format the output of any that contain the exact string passed in with search term and continue printing out the rest of the results with a different text formatting.

Comment: What I don't understand from your answer is what the behavior should be. In your example, if we skip empties then print any matching terms and also print terms that don't match... we're just printing everything. There is no search. Instead of describing the logic, can you describe what you want the behavior to be?

Comment: ok, so you want to always print all results, but the results that match the search should print differently than the ones that don't match?

Comment: @melcher yes, the rpc link the results come from returns a rough set of 'matches' which contain bits and pieces of the searchterm, but exactly yes, i want to highlight those that actually contain the searchterm, but without skipping all the others.

Comment: It looks like the `n += 1` line should not be in the `unless...else...end` conditional (which is hard to read anyway).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:
Based on some back and forth the desired behavior is to print matched results differently from unmatched results.

So, in Ruby you have access to "functional" patterns like select, map, reduce, etc. that can be useful for what you're doing here.

It's also advantageous to separate functionality into different methods (e.g. one that searches, one that turns them into a string, one that prints the output). This is just an example of how to break it down, but splitting up the responsibilities makes it much easier to test and see which function isn't doing what you want by examining the intermediate structures.

Also, I'm not sure how you want to "match" the search term, so I used `String#include?` but you can replace that with whatever matching algorithm you like.

But I think you're looking for something like this:

```rb
def makelist(jsn, searchterm)
  jsn.select do |package|
    package["Name"] && package["Description"]
  end.map do |package|
    if matches?(package, searchterm)
      matched_package_to_string(package)
    else
      package_to_string(package)
    end
  end.join("\n")
end
def matches?(package, searchterm)
  package['Name'].include?(searchterm) || package('Description').include?(searchterm)
end
def matched_package_to_string(package)
  pkname = package["Name"]
  pkdesc = package["Description"]
  pkver  = package["Version"]
  "#{fmt(fmt("aur/", 6),0)}#{fmt(pkname,0)} [#{fmt(pkver,8)}]\n    #{pkdesc}"
end
def package_to_string(package)
  # Not sure how these should print
end
```

Comment: thank you so much, took a little tweaking to retro fit it to my functional writing style, but this was EXACTLY what I was looking for, thank you so much!